# Insufficient diskspace when installing oracle express 10g

Tags: 14.04, oracle

i just downloaded and about to install oracle express edition 10g based on [this site](http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.com/2013/03/installing-oracle-xe-on-ubuntu-32-bit.html).

this is what come up when i try to install it:

```
$ dpkg -i oracle-xe_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 200359 files and directories currently installed.) 
Preparing to unpack oracle-xe_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386.deb ... 
You have insufficient diskspace in the destination directory (/usr/lib) to  install Oracle Database 10g Express Edition.
The installation requires at  least 1.5 GB free on this disk. 
dpkg: error processing archive oracle-xe_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386.deb (--install):  
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1 
Errors were encountered while processing:  
oracle-xe_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386.deb
```

I have read that the requirement to install, is to have 1.5GB free space on `/usr/lib` directory, and in mine it written 1.6GB free space.

Is there anyway to install this on a different disk (`/usr/lib`)?
or if there is not, how to free some space on it?

I'm new in ubuntu by the way, i started using it a month ago (and still have windows on the otherside).

---

as requested by muru, here's the output from df -h and lsblk
image link : http://s16.postimg.org/ubzkueybp/askubuntu.png

Comment: Please add the output of  `df -h` and `lsblk`.

Comment: hey muru, you can check the output on the image link above, thanks before~

Answer (score 0):

To free some space in the system, try this:

1. Remove the unnecessary packages: `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`
2. Remove the unnecessary packages' cached installers: `sudo apt-get autoclean`

If it's not enough:

3. Delete the content of the `/var/log/` folder: `sudo rm -rf /var/log/*`

Comment: i did the command above and however, my /usr/lib is still 1.6GB, therefore i (still) can't install oracle xe. thanks for your reply by the way